# Body Hairs and Cycling?

Tags: health, body-hair

Still, another of problem most of the cyclist go through "Body Hairs". For guys with long hair all over the body, cycling is another way of punishing that guy (hopefully not me). Especially, the most problematic hair in my body are from thigh, they trouble be lot if not mitigated properly. I have tried shaving them, burning them (O.o) or other wild ways.

What is the proper way to get rid of the body hairs from cycling point of view?

Comment: Might be worth linking to the reasons why cyclists de-hair in the first place: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44/why-do-cyclists-shave-their-legs

Comment: "Proper" will be a matter of opinion, but I can't think of a better way to ask this. (Substituting "most effective" or whatever would just be playing games with words.)

Comment: @Neil You could use "normal" or "best" as adjectives.

Comment: @ChrisW - Yeah, but both of those are subject to interpretation as well. That's why I left this alone; the intent is fairly clear, I think.

Comment: Consider a well-groomed beard could be an aero advantage, if it helps the airflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your options for temporary hair removal are:

- **Razor Blade:** Pros - cheap, easy to do for most areas. Cons - you won't stay smooth for long, regrowth is stubbly, you can cut yourself.
- **Electric Razor:** Pros - very cheap, very easy to do for most areas. Cons - you won't stay smooth for long, regrowth is stubbly.
- **Depilatory Cream:** Pros - fairly cheap, fairly easy to do for most areas, reasonable results, stays smooth for a reasonable length of time. Cons - smells,  potential for chemical burns if you get it wrong.
- **Waxing:** Pros - good results, stays smooth for a long time (probably a few weeks). Cons - can be painful, difficult to do yourself, expensive (and possibly embarrassing) to get it done professionally.
- **Epilator:** Pros - very cheap, easy to do for most areas, good results, stays smooth for a long time. Cons - hurts like hell.

Comment: The other option is riding on the hairs and having the motion of cycling pull them out by the roots.

Comment: Nice answer. Do any cyclists ever go for laser hair removal?

Comment: What about "Electrolysis"...http://www.medicinenet.com/electrolysis/article.htm

Answer (score 1):

I'll confess to shaving my butt (with an electric trimmer) prior to a long ride.  This largely alleviates "butt burn".

But leg hairs don't seem to be a problem when I wear standard cycling shorts.  I have had leg hair problems, though, when wearing other types of shorts.  (My legs aren't all that hairy, though.)